# Fixed width widget in QSplitter

Tags: c++, qt5

I have 3 `QWidget`s placed into one horizontal `QSplitter`. So there is left, central and right `QWidget`. And I have 2 grappling point (is this how is it called?): between left/central and central/right `QWidget`s.

What I want is to have central widget of fixed width, so when I move oned grappling point left/right, the other one should move exactly the same way.

I've tried setting horizontal policy of `QSizePolicy` of central widget to `Fixed` and `Minimum`. Also I've tried horizontal stretch for left and right widgets to 1, but none of these helped.

Answer (score 2):

[QWidget::setFixedWidth](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedWidth) applied to the widget you would like to have a fixed width. That one of course wants you to specify that width.

Comment: This has one disadvantage: I need to pass the width, which I don't know as it depends on text translations etc

Comment: You may pass a relative fixed width, say, 1/3 of entire rectangle area.